# Rails Search add more items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is my search code in products model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('lower(name) LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

Problem is it is only making search for name only how do I add more search items like descriptions.

I tried to add it through this code but it is throwing an error:

```
  def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('lower(name) LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

Error is :

wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: lower(name) LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?

My code in controller:

```
@user_products = Product.search params[:search]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed another search parameter for description to assemble in query.
Try this

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('lower(name) LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```